# Print msflexgrid with picture in cell in VB6 

Tags: vb6, image, msflexgrid

How do I print `msflexgrid` with a picture in some of its cells in VB6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to first select the grid cell, optionally set the cell picture alignment, then load the picture using either `LoadPicture` (if you are using a file path to a picture on disk) or preferably `LoadResPicture` (if you are using a picture in a resource file) e.g.

```
  With MSFlexGrid1
    .Row = 1
    .Col = 1
    .RowSel = 1
    .ColSel = 1
    .CellAlignment = flexAlignCenterCenter
    Set .CellPicture = LoadPicture("C:\My Pictures\Me.bmp")
    ' Alternatively:
    ' Set .CellPicture = LoadResPicture(MY_PROFILE_PIC_ID)
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  the problem here is that i am creating the picture dynamically from text typed  by the user using. is there another way